# Was bedeutet der Ausdruck: “Die Suche nach der Nadel im Heuhaufen?”’

Tags: meaning, word-usage, history

Woher kommt die Redewendung: Die Suche nach der  Nadel im Heuhaufen?

Was ist damit gemeint?

Für welchen Ausdruck im Englischen ist dies eine deutsche Entsprechung?

Comment: Ich wāre dankbar, wenn mir jemand eine mögliche Erklärung für den down vote und das close geben kōnnte, merci <3

Comment: Das sind eigentlich drei Fragen. Zur Bedeutung kann man einfach entsprechende Nachschlagewerke zu Rate ziehen,beispielsweise [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Stecknadel), erstes Beispiel im Abschnitt  "bildlich", das ist ziemlich klar *off-topic*. Für das englische Gegenstück ist das hier das falsche Forum, also auch *off-topic*. Bleibt: *woher kommt*: wenn ein Bild so naheliegend ist, dass es in mehrerern Sprachen verwendet wird, ist der aus einer Antwort zu ziehehnde Nutzen nicht gerade gigantisch.

Comment: danke, guidot, das leuchtet mir ein. also heisst das:
was in einem Nachschlagwerk zu finden ist, gehört nicht hier her, richtig
und trotzdem

Comment: also: wenn ein Fremdsprachiger eine Redewendung auf Deutsch übersetzen will, und die wortwörtlich gemacht werden kann, ist meine Frage obsolet. Einverstanden! und trotzdem: es ist noch nicht erklärt: weshalb ausgerechnet eine Nadel?
es könnte auch ein Hühenrei oder ein Ehering sein.
Wäre dann z.B. die Information, die Redewendung kommt daher, dass ein Schneider seine Nähnadel verloren hat oder eine Magd ihre Haarnadel ...
und dies  mit einem literarischen Werk von Schiller oder Gotthelf oder einem Spruch aus der Bibel dokumentiert werden könnte, wäre dann die Frage angemessen für diesen SE?

Comment: "Bleibt: woher kommt: wenn ein Bild so naheliegend ist, dass es in mehrerern Sprachen verwendet wird, ist der aus einer Antwort zu ziehehnde Nutzen nicht gerade gigantisch." Richtig.  Und wäre das Bild in anderen Sprachen nicht wörtlich identisch, dann könnte die Frage und ihre Beantwortung sehr wohl von Nutzen sein.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: zur "General Reference" haben wir mal ein schönes Schaubild gemacht: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/wann-soll-ich-welchen-schlie%c3%9fgrund-bei-fragen-nach-%c3%9cbersetzungen-bedeutungen-u - nicht alles, was im irgendeinem Wörterbuch zu finden sein könnte ist gleich *off topic*. Die Etymologie hier ist nicht banal, also *on topic* und von allgemeinem Interesse. Du solltest dich aber auf eine Haupt-Frage beschränken, also den Titel evtl. anpassen, denn Bedeutung und Übersetzung findet man recht einfach in einem Wörterbuch.

Comment: ganz herzlichen Dank, Takkat. Ich habe mir das Schaubild runtergeladen und werde es studieren! Ich würde vorschlagen, diese Information als link ganz am Anfang der Tour einzublenden  und ebenso  zu oberst im Help Center! "HOW TO ASK".
Oder ist das nur für die Administratoren?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: die Tour und unsere Help Seiten sollen klein und übersichtlich bleiben. Close-Votes kommen erst für Benutzer ab 500 Reputationspunkten in Betracht und dann hoffen wir, dass diese mit unserer Seite vertraut sind. Die Meta-Seite ist aber als FAQ markiert, damit man sie schneller finden kann (Du kannst nach den "Tags" suchen).

Comment: Es gibt noch [diese Meta Q&A](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-about-meaning-translations-or-difference) zu der wir in unserem [help/on-topic] und auch wenn eine Frage geschlossen wurde verlinken. Zu unerklärlichen Downvotes habe ich einmal auf einer [Schwester-Seite etwas geschrieben](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15081/3940).

Comment: FWIW: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/120226/99685.

Comment: Danke für den Link. Es wurde schon erwähnt, dass More den Ausdruck gebraucht hat, aber dieser war sicher schon viel älter. Dass mit der Nadel ursprünglich ein Strohhalm gemeint war, daran habe ich auch schon gedacht.

Comment: @Albrecht: es steht nirgendwo, dass ursprünglich ein Strohhalm gemeint war. Die Bemerkung mit dem Strohhalm wurde nur gemacht nach einem Vortrag über Steganographie, eine Technick die es zu Zeiten von More noch nicht gab. Steganographie ist schwieriger als die Suche nach einer Nadel, sie est eher wie die Suche nach einem Strohhalm in einem Heuhaufen: man sucht ja nach (vielleicht nicht einmal vorhandenen) Bits in einem Meer von Bits.

Comment: Wir kommen der Sache näher: Die Nadel war nicht eine Nadel und der Heuhafen war eine Wiese.

Comment: Ihr habt alle keine Ahnung!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die *Suche nach der Nadel im Heuhaufen* gibt es in vielen Sprachen, auch auf Englisch, wenn man eine schwierige Suche unternimmt:

> searching for a needle in a haystack

Mehrere Quellen sind sich einig, dass die [Etymologie dieser Redewendung](https://www.etymonline.com/word/needle) wohl auf  St. Thomas More zurück geht, der bereits 1530 schrieb:

> To seke out one lyne in all hys bookes wer to go looke a **nedle in a meadow**.

Es handelt sich also um eine ursprünglich englische Redewednung, die dann in viele Sprachen übersetzt wurde. Auf einer solchen, [freien Übersetzung](https://sites.psu.edu/astrowright/2018/06/07/a-needle-in-a-haystack/) basiert auch die fälschliche Annahme, die Herkunft sei aus Don Quichotte, denn in der spanischen Originalfassung ist sie nicht enthalten.

Über die erstmalige Verwendung im deutschen Sprachraum gibt es widersprüchliche oder nur schwammige Aussagen (im 19. Jahrhundert oder früher<sup>[3](https://www.sprichwoerter-redewendungen.de/redewendungen/die-nadel-im-heuhaufen-suchen/)</sup>), dies scheint also nicht eindeutig geklärt.

Comment: Dazu muss man wissen, die Quellenlage vor dem 15 JH ist relativ unzuverlässig.

Comment: @vectory: das ist korrekt und es ist ein allgemeines Problem der Etymologie. Offenbar hat man keine auch nur annähernd so alten deutschen oder anderssprachigen Quellen gefunden.

Answer (score 3):

Die englische Entsprechung für "Nadel im Heuhaufen" ist die wörtliche Übersetzung: "A needle in a haystack".

Die Bedeutung ist eigentlich nicht schwer zu erraten, aber der Vollständigkeit halber: Eine Nadel ist in einem Heuhaufen schwer zu finden (Metalldetektoren gab es früher nicht). Daher steht die "Suche nach der Nadel im Heuhafen" für eine schwierige Suche.

Comment: *Heu im Nadelhaufen* zu finden stelle ich mir deutlich schwieriger vor.

Comment: das sind doch zwei phantastische Hinweise! und den mit den Metalldetekoren finde ich gut: Luther würde wohl das Gleichnis vom Schatz im Acker  heute mit 
einem "Goldsucher" an einem Touristenstrand vergleichen.

Comment: Zentrifuge, Wasserbad, ein starkes Gebläse...? :)

Comment: @userunknown Im Haufen sollte gesucht, dieser aber nicht unbedingt zerstört werden.

Comment: Das Sprichwort unterstreicht nur die Aussichtslosigkeit des Unterfangens. Ob man das tun soll und zu Randbedingungen äußert es sich nicht. Versuche, den Ausdruck auf große Holznadeln zurückzuführen unterlaufen die Bedeutung, die das Sprichwort hat - man sucht ewig mit ungewissen Erfolg.

Answer (score -3):

> Was bedeutet der Ausdruck: “Die Suche nach der Nadel im Heuhaufen?”

**Vor der Suche nach der Nadel im Heuhaufen muss gewarnt werden!**

Ich bin der Frage selber nochmals nachgegangen:

Die Redewendung ist tatsächlich in vielen Sprachen gebräuchlich: Portugiesisch, Dänisch, Russisch, Polnisch, Chinesisch, Ukrainisch, Französisch, Griechisch, Hebräisch, ... eigentlich ubiquitär!
Und immer wird gesagt, dass sie schon für ein paar hundert Jahre nachgewiesen werden kann und sicher noch viel älter ist!

Die Bedeutung: ein  winziges Teil in einem grossen Haufen suchen, wäre da schon ein wenig banal, wenn nicht ...

Aber im Hinblick auf meine Antwort, die ich gleich geben werde, ist dieser Kommentar von Guidot schon fast ein bisschen voreilig, wenn nicht naseweis oder sogar frech:

*Zur Bedeutung kann man einfach entsprechende Nachschlagewerke zu Rate ziehen,beispielsweise DWDS, erstes Beispiel im Abschnitt "bildlich", das ist ziemlich klar off-topic. Für das englische Gegenstück ist das hier das falsche Forum, also auch off-topic. Bleibt: woher kommt: wenn ein Bild so naheliegend ist, dass es in mehrerern Sprachen verwendet wird, ist der aus einer Antwort zu ziehehnde Nutzen nicht gerade gigantisch.*

Ein winziges Ding suchen in einem grossen Durcheinander?

Ja, warum dann ausgerechnet eine Nadel? Eine Haarspange, vielleicht?

Hat es da der Bauer mit der Magd getrieben? Und sucht jetzt seine Frau das Corpus delicti? Weit gefehlt!

Wenn ich denke, was man alles in einem Heuhaufen verlieren kann: Warum nicht das Messer? Einen Nagel? einen Groschen? einen Esel? oder die Heugabel? Jetzt kommen wir der Sache schon auf die Spur:

Ich habe mir die folgende Seite mit google übersetzen lassen:

https://www.haaretz.co.il/gallery/art/.premium-1.2486797

**Ist eine Nadelsuche im Heuhaufen eine Kunst?**

Im Palais de Tokyo in Paris glauben sie, dass es so ist: Am Ende der Woche wurde ein riesiger Strohhaufen aufgestellt und ein italienischer Künstler verbrachte fast 18 Stunden damit, eine Nadel zu finden

Seit Hunderten von Jahren, seit die Phrase "eine Nadel im Heuhaufen finden" geprägt wurde, wird sie in vielen Sprachen verwendet, darunter auch im Hebräischen. Am Ende der Woche erhielt er im Palais de Tokyo Museum in Paris eine wörtliche, künstlerische Interpretation: In einer Ausstellung namens Inside legte der italienische Künstler Sven Sachsenberg einen Strohhaufen - oder Heu - auf und suchte nach einer kleinen Nadel.

Sven Sachsenberg ist Künstler von Marathon-Projekten, in denen er den Alltag in seiner Heimatstadt Südtirol und anderen Regionen reflektiert. In seinen Projekten hat er bereits giftige Pilze gegessen oder einen Tag in einem Raum mit einer Kuh geschlossen. An einem anderen Tag widmete er sich der Glocke, die aufhörte zu klingeln, und während er sich auf der Kante ausbalancierte, klopfte er jede Stunde darauf. Er sägte sogar durch die Äste eines Baumes, den er bis zum unvermeidlichen Fall hinaufgestiegen war.

Sachsenberg ist immer die zentrale Figur in seiner Arbeit, und dieses Mal suchte er nach einer Nadel, die der Museumspräsident auf einem Haufen versteckte. **”Es ist nicht zu schwer, ich mache nur Strohkugeln und überprüfe sie einzeln.** Das einzige Risiko ist, dass ich ein Abdecker bin", sagte er den Reportern eines Fernsehsenders, der den Marathon absolvierte, der natürlich 24 Stunden dauerte.

Dieses Vertrauen zog er von einem ähnlichen Marathon in London vor zwei Jahren, wo er innerhalb von sechs Stunden die Nadel fand. Aber diesmal war der Stapel größer - er wog 450 Kilogramm -, und die Suche dauerte länger: 17 Stunden und 45 Minuten waren nötig, um die lang erwartete Nadel zu finden. Es ist nur Strohhalm und Becher ", sagte einer der Zuschauer.

[image]

Ein interessanter Kommentar ist übrigens:

Was passiert, wenn er herausfindet, dass auf Hebräisch eine Nadel in einem Haufen “Esel" heißt?

**”Es ist nicht zu schwer, ich mache nur Strohkugeln und überprüfe sie einzeln.**

Genau so geht die Suche nach der Nadel im Heuhaufen:

**Ein winziges Detail in einem grossen Chaos herausfinden.**

Jawohl,

**der Teufel steckt im Detail! Und ehe man ihn gefunden hat, da hat er einem schon gestochen.**

Darum ist es eine Nadel. Und ja, es könnte auch ein Nagel oder die Heugabel gewesen sein!

Eigentlich habe ich mir gedacht, der Ursprung sei im Alten Testament zu finden, aber “die Schlange wird dich in die Ferse stechen” kann es nicht gewesen sein, obschon ich mal in eine Mistgabel getreten bin.

**Die Suche nach der Herkunft der Redensart “die Suche nach der Nadel im Heuhaufen” hat sich als eine Suche nach der Nadel im Heuhaufen erwiesen!**

Comment: Eine Antwort ist das nicht, doch interessant. Bei den Griechen ist es scheinbar ein Floh im Heu. Angenommen die Nadel wäre originär und der Floh nur eine (homophone) Ableitung zu was kleinem, könnte der Spruch auch *etwas wertvolles in einem Haufen schlechtes* bedeuten. Vgl. eben Hbr. שחת (sahat) "hay", bzw. Aram. "decompose" (vgl. *Kompost*?), Ugarit. "bush, shrub", Klass. Syrisch "armpit; duckweed, water parsnip; eminences". Nach meiner Vermutung, es handele sich um die Suche nach einer Person im Heu, denke ich, es gehe eher um's (Getreide-)Feld.

Comment: Tatsächlich steht bei *field, area* u.a. Egypt. *sht*. Übrigens, בערימת "im Haufen" enthält ב "im" und scheinbar עיר ('ir) "city", bzw. בעיר (bi'ir) "to burn, destruct". Nur nicht bi'irren lassen, meinetwegen solls auch gerne um eine Haarnadel/-Spange gehen. Fraglich wäre, ob bzw. seit wann es den Spruch so in Hebräisch gibt, oder ob das nur eine wörtliche Übersetzung etwa aus dem Englischen ist, bzw. ob das Deutsche ebenso, wie Takkat nahelegen will, geklont ist und all die anderen Sprachen auch, bspw. [hier](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/needle_in_a_haystack). Hbr. steht dort grad nicht.

Comment: Deine Vermutung, dass es sich um einen Spion handeln könnte, der sich im Feld versteckt, erscheint mir immer plausibler. Also könnte die Phrase aus einer Zeit der grossen militärischen Weltreiche stammen. Wo sind die Lateiner geblieben? Ich habe noch gar nicht die Römer gegoogelt!

Comment: Ich habe noch eine andere Erklärung gefunden, die mir noch viel mehr einleuchtet als die, dass man sich beim Suchen nach einer Nadel im Heu  in die Finger stechen kann und das daher eine heikle Angelegenheit ist. Aber die verrate ich euch erst, wenn ich entweder auf null reputation down- oder auf 1000 up gevotet worden bin.

Comment: Das wäre ja *Bestechung* oder eher unlautere Vorteilnahme.

Comment: Genau: Bestechung mit der Nadel im Heuhaufen!

Comment: 1005, wenn ich nun bitten darf? Aber schnell, bevor es wieder weniger wird ;-)

Comment: nur noch für dich vectory:
die anderen interessierts eh nicht  mehr! auf der English Language Site hat mal jemand die gleiche Frage gestellt, ich habe das erst hier vor ein paar Wochen mitbekommen. Und die OP hat gesagt, sie hätte gemeint, es sei vielleicht ein Spiel gewesen. Und es hiess dort, bei Thomas More habe der Heuhaufen ursprunglich eine Wiese bedeutet. Wenn der Heuhaufen mal eine Wiese war, warum die Nadel nicht ein Stock oder ein Knochen? Also: Inzwischen bin ich fast überzeugt, dass damit mal  ein Kinderspiel  gemeint war, das heute noch Hundebesitzer mit ihrem Hundchen spielen ..

Comment: Ein Spiel ist definitionsgemäß aufregend, spaßig oder wenigstens einfach und lehrreich. Man kann natürlich ein Spiel aus der Such nach dem Splitter im Pferdefutter machen, der erste gewinnt den größten Pudding. Schlangenjagd ist "die Simpsons" zufolge sogar Folkssport.

Comment: Ach so, dann war es eben eine Sportart in den ersten Hochkulturen!

Comment: [Diesem Bild](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/32541/34512) riesiger Stäbe entsprechend, sowie einem Vergleich zwischen En. *lathe* "4. (obsolete) granary, barn" und "Lanze" oder "Latte", drängt sich mir der Verdacht einer äußerst großen Nadel und eines eher weniger friedlichen Spiels auf. Dabei suche ich verkrampft nach einem Reim der Entsprechungen für *Nadel* und *Heuhaufen*. Die Suche nach *Lot in the plot*, nach dem *Los im Lös* ... dem *Stoß im Stuss*, Sie verstehen?

Comment: Eine weitere--hoffentlich die letzte--Idee fällt mir wieder bei "ladle" ein, relativ unabhängig davon: Die Spreu vom Weizen zu trennen heißt, das gute zwischen dem Streugut zu finden, vgl. *threshold, thresh, trash, Rasensprenger, sprühen* etc und vorallem *Stroh*. Vgl. aber auch *little*. Tatsächlich begegnet mir gerade immer wieder PIE \*klew- "small, bend", bzw. auch \ *(s)kleh₂w- (“to hook; trip up; hamper; block; shut out; close”), vgl. *\*kleh₂u-* (“nail, pin, hook - instruments, of old use for locking doors”), *Schlüssel, clavus* "Nagel*, sowie *Heu*, von \*kewh₂- "to beat, hew, forge".

Comment: Du Guter! hast mich auf die endgültige Lösung gebracht: Wenn der Heustok eine meadow war, dann muss die Nadel ein arrow gewesen sein. Denken wir nur an die Vogeljagd mit Pfeil und Bogen: Die Abbildungen liegen 10'000 bis 40'000 Jahre zurück! Darum die weltweite Verbreitung der Wendung. Stell dir vor, wie lange man an einem gute Pfeil gearbeitet hat, und welche Mühe es die Steinzeitmenschen beanspruchte, einen verschossenen Pfeil zu finden. Wilhelm Tell kann uns davon ein Liedlein singen. Ich werde die Frage nun in der SE "History" stellen. Und Du kannst dort antworten. Akzeptiert im voraus!

Answer (score -4):

Der Spruch ist weit verbreitet und könnte gut und gerne aus einer alten Tradition stammen.

> E. Piirainen, "Folk Narratives and Legends as Sources of widespread Idioms: Toward a Lexikon of Common Figurative Units" [[1](https://doi.org/10.7592/FEJF2011.48.piirainen), [2](https://www.ceeol.com/search/article-detail?id=70775)]
>
> ***to look for a needle in a haystack***
>
> ‘to  look  for  something  that  is  impossible  to  find;  to  be  bothered  with searching without any prospect of success’
>
> There  are  many  folktales  of  vain  searches  for  objects.  Probably,  the  idiom refers to one of them, although the story of a fool who is hunting for a needle in a haystack is not as widespread. Grimms’ fairy tale 
>   *Clever Hans* (KHM No.32) tells about a fool who puts a needle into a hay cart. Here we want to point to the Yiddish idiom (Appendix 1) which uses the concept **Haywagon**. There may be a connection with an old proverb (*Si acum quaereres, acum invenisses* ‘Who wants to search a needle, would also find it’, reported by Plautus and Menander 238), although the element **Hay** is missing here.<sup>9</sup>
>
> <sub>The full data reported by our informants are presented in the Appendix 1 below, illustrating that idiom equivalents are remarkably widespread. They exist not only in most of the European standard languages but also in a number of the minor and minority languages and even in some non-European languages. The causes of the “popularity” of this idiom in all these languages are still unclear. It is most probable that the idioms go back to one and the same textual source, although this source has not been established definitely.</sub>
>
> <sup>9</sup>  See also AT 1685; EM 9, 1137ff
>
> AT = Aarne, Antti & Thompson, Stith 1961. *The Types of the Folktale. A Classification and Bibliography*. Helsinki: Suomalainen Tiedeakatemia.
>
> EM = *Enzyklopädie des Märchens. Handwörterbuch zur historischen und vergleichenden Erzählforschung* 2010. Vol. 13. Berlin: de Gruyter.
>
> [Smallcaps nicht richtig wiedergegeben]

Der Appendix ist beachtlich, doch da auch eine Übersetzung in Esperanto genannt wird, ist zweifelhaft, wie Aussagekräftig die Liste ist. Griechisch z.B. fehlt wiederum. Dennoch ist die Grundidee nicht untypisch, denn in der vergleichenden Mythologie, was hier als Überbegriff zählen darf, werden des öfteren weit entfernte Kulturkreise verglichen.

Edit: Nachdem (*trotzdem*) meine Theorie nicht gut angenommen wurde, da ich behaupte die Nadel bezeichne eventuell einen Spion, gibt es nun doch noch einen Nachtrag. Und zwar ist die rekonstruierte Wurzel für *Nadel* und *nähen* Proto Indo Europäisch \sneh1- "to spin, twist". Dies ist recht nah an der Wurzeln für En. *snake* "Schlange", auch "kriechen", vgl. *sneak*. Man denke an Zick-Zack-förmige Schlangenlinien, bzw. Stichmuster beim *Nähen* (gleiche Wurzel), und andere Metaphern, sowie bezeichnender Weise die verräterische Schlange in der Sagenwelt, die sich auch Sprachlich niederschlägt. Zudem sind Schlangen im Heuhaufen oder im hohen Graß tatsächlich eine Gefahr.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90299/discussion-on-answer-by-vectory-was-bedeutet-der-ausdruck-die-suche-nach-der-n).